# Why mapping sftp disc returns fuse: invalid argument

Tags: linux, debian, sshfs

Why mapping sftp disc returns this error? Am I doing it wrong?

```
$ sshfs user@host:/ /home/absolut/Pulpit/sftp fuse umask=0,defaults,noauto,user,allow_other 0 0
user@host's password: 
fuse: invalid argument `fuse'
```

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `sshfs` (and other FUSE tools) differs from what one usually writes to `/etc/fstab`. See [man page of sshfs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sshfs) for details.

Command like this should work for you:

```
sshfs user@host:/ /home/absolut/Pulpit/sftp
```